# How to programatically set Shortcuts TargetPath to a website?

Tags: powershell, object, shortcut

I want to use powershell to modify the TargetPath of a shortcut to open a website
I found the below script that almost works

```
function Set-Shortcut {
  param(
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
  $LinkPath,
  $Hotkey,
  $IconLocation,
  $Arguments,
  $TargetPath
  )
  begin {
    $shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
  }

  process {
    $link = $shell.CreateShortcut($LinkPath)

    $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.GetEnumerator() |
      Where-Object { $_.key -ne 'LinkPath' } |
      ForEach-Object { $link.$($_.key) = $_.value }
    $link.Save()
  }
}
```

However

```
Set-Shortcut -LinkPath "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.lnk" -TargetPath powershell start process "www.youtube.com"
```

Will default out to attaching a default path if you do not define one to look like:

```
"C:\Users\micha\Desktop\powershell start process "www.youtube.com""
```

how do I get rid of that default file path?

BONUS:
I'd be appreciative if someone broke down this line of code:

```
ForEach-Object { $link.$($_.key) = $_.value }
```

Comment: A shortcut to open a website is a different file format alltogether with extension .Url. Why do you want to start PowerShell.exe and have that open the site in the default browser? It can be done, but then the `TargetPath` should be just the path to powershell.exe and whatever you want PowerShel tyo do goes in the `Arguments`.

Comment: Your sample call is inconsistent with the symptom - it would create an error. `ForEach-Object { $link.$($_.key) = $_.value }` sets, for each parameter passed (reflected in automatic variable `$_`) a property with the same name as the parameter to the parameter value. E.g, `-TargetPath powerShell` results in `$link.TargetPath = 'powershell'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to change the properties of the shortcut object directly?

Try this and let me know:

```
function Set-Shortcut {

[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [System.String]$FilePath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1)]
    [System.String]$TargetPath
)

Begin {
    $shell = new-object -ComObject WScript.Shell
}

Process {
    try {
        $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $FilePath -ErrorAction Stop

        $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($file.FullName)
        $shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetPath
        $shortcut.Save()    
    }
    catch {
        throw $PSItem
    }
}

End {
    while ($result -ne -1) {
        $result = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shell)
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot ONE single curly bracket but it worked perfectly so you are incredibly appreciated

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!